# How to use the output from OneHotEncoder in sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification, one-hot-encoding

I have a Pandas Dataframe with 2 categorical variables, and ID variable and a target variable (for classification). I managed to convert the categorical values with `OneHotEncoder`. This results in a sparse matrix.

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
# First I remapped the string values in the categorical variables to integers as OneHotEncoder needs integers as input
... remapping code ...

ohe.fit(df[['col_a', 'col_b']])
ohe.transform(df[['col_a', 'col_b']])
```

But I have no clue how I can use this sparse matrix in a DecisionTreeClassifier? Especially when I want to add some other non-categorical variables in my dataframe later on. Thanks!

**EDIT**
In reply to the comment of miraculixx: I also tried the DataFrameMapper in sklearn-pandas

```
mapper = DataFrameMapper([
    ('id_col', None),
    ('target_col', None),
    (['col_a'], OneHotEncoder()),
    (['col_b'], OneHotEncoder())
])

t = mapper.fit_transform(df)
```

But then I get this error:

> TypeError: no supported conversion for types : (dtype('O'),
>   dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64')).

Comment: [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas) is really helpful when working with dataframes and sklearn.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see you are already using Pandas, so why not using its `get_dummies` function?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['rick','young'],['phil','old'],['john','teenager']],columns=['name','age-group'])
```

result

```
   name age-group
0  rick     young
1  phil       old
2  john  teenager
```

now you encode with get_dummies

```
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

result

```
name_john  name_phil  name_rick  age-group_old  age-group_teenager  \
0          0          0          1              0                   0   
1          0          1          0              1                   0   
2          1          0          0              0                   1   

   age-group_young  
0                1  
1                0  
2                0
```

And you can actually use the new Pandas DataFrame in your Sklearn's DecisionTreeClassifier.

Comment: Thanks Guiem Bosch, that worked. However, I had to specify to use the get_dummies only on the two columns. If I left the ID variable in the Dataframe I got the message that my kernel died. So the following code worked: pd.get_dummies(df[['col_a', 'col_b']])

Comment: Additionally, the remapping of string values to integers is not necessary. Otherwize get_dummies doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example from scikit-learn:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_feature_transformation.html#example-ensemble-plot-feature-transformation-py

Problem is that you are not using the sparse matrices to `xx.fit()`. You are using the original data.